# solving the limit $\lim (\frac{x}{x-1}-\frac{1}{\ln x})\, \, \text{as } x\to1$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to1}\left(\frac{x}{x-1}-\frac{1}{\ln{x}}\right)$$

Without l'Hospital.

Help me with this Excercises.. I cant do it!! Someone who could help me!!

Comment: Are you allowed to use series?

Comment: this question was already posted in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554629/find-the-limit-lim-limits-x-to-1-left-fracxx-1-frac1-l?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

If you can prove without l'Hospital rule the following two limits
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln (1+y)}{y}=1,\ \ \ \ \ \ and\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln (1+y)-y}{y^{2}}=-\frac{1}{2}
$$
then it suffices to re-write the function as follows: Put $x=1+y,$ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}f(x) &=&\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{(1+y)\ln (1+y)-y}{%
y\ln (1+y)} \\
&=&\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{\ln (1+y)-y}{y^{2}}+\frac{\ln (1+y)}{y}}{%
\frac{\ln (1+y)}{y}} \\
&=&\frac{-\frac{1}{2}+1}{1}=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Of course this is really L'Hospital's rule in disguise, but still, nice. +1

Comment: The first limit is by defintion the derivative of $ln(1+y)$ at $y=0$ since $ln(1+0)=0$

Answer (score 1):

we will show that the limit is zero.

make a change of variable $x = 1 + h$ or $h = 1 - x.$ as $x$ gets closer to $1, h$ gets closer to $0.$ we will use the fact $\ln(1 + h) = h + \cdots.$

so $\lim_{x \to 1}  ( { x \over x - 1} - {1 \over \ln x}) = 
\lim_{h \to 0} ({1+h \over h} - {1 \over h + \cdots}) = \lim_{h \to 0}{h^2 \over h} = 0$

i made a mistake. the limit is infact half.
i needed one more correction term in $ln(1+h) = h - \frac{1}{2}h^2 + \cdots$ instead of just $\ln(1 + h) = h + \cdots$  the corrected version is then,

so $\lim_{x \to 1}  ( { x \over x - 1} - {1 \over \ln x}) = 
\lim_{h \to 0} ({1+h \over h} - {1 \over h -\frac{1}{2}h^2+ \cdots}) = 
\lim_{h \to 0}{{(1+h)(h - \frac{1}{2}h^2 + \cdots) -h} \over h(h + \cdots)} = \lim_{h \to 0}{{h + h^2 - \frac{1}{2}h^2 + \cdots - h}\over {h^2 + \cdots}} = {1 \over 2} $

Comment: That "fact" you are using is very dangerous in calculating limits. In fact, your answer is wrong.

Comment: @imranfat, i know where the error is. i will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a substitution $lnx=t$ then $t$ goes to zero.
You then get the expression $\frac{te^t-e^t+1}{te^t-t}$ on which the limit has to be taken. Now using series for the e-power: $1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+...$ and put that into the expression, we get $\frac{(1+t+0.5t^2...)x-1-t-0.5t^2...+1}{(1+t+0.5t^2...)t-t}$. Enfin, work out brackets and terms are canceling, including a quadratic term. We end up with $\frac{1+0.5t...-0.5}{1+...}$ so taking the limit becomes 0.5. Maybe not so elegant, but no Hospital

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but it does show a slick way to evaluate the limit if you *assume* the limit exists.

Note first that

$$\lim_{x\to1}\left({x\over x-1}-{1\over\ln x}\right)=\lim_{x\to1}\left(1+{1\over x-1}-{1\over\ln x}\right)=1+\lim_{x\to1}\left({1\over x-1}-{1\over\ln x}\right)$$

so it suffices to evaluate the latter limit.  Let's call it $L$.  If this limit exists, we can also write it as a limit with $x=u^2$, i.e.,

$$\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{x\to1}\left({1\over x-1}-{1\over\ln x}\right)\\
&=\lim_{u\to1}\left({1\over u^2-1}-{1\over\ln u^2}\right)\\
&=\lim_{u\to1}\left({1/2\over u-1}-{1/2\over u+1}-{1\over2\ln u}\right)\\
&=-{1\over2}\lim_{u\to1}\left(1\over u+1\right)+{1\over2}\lim_{u\to1}\left({1\over u-1}-{1\over\ln u}\right)\\
&=-{1\over4}+{1\over2}L
\end{align}$$

so $L=-1/2$, which makes the original limit equal to $1-1/2=1/2$.

Note, this does *not* prove that the limit exists.  One reason why not is that the only property of the logarithm the derivation uses is that $\ln u^2=2\ln u$, which means it could care less that we're using the *natural* logarithm.  But the limit clearly cannot exist, much less be the same, for two different bases of logarithm.