# Spot mistake in finding $\lim \limits_{x\to1}\left(\frac x {x-1} - \frac1 {\log(x)} \right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, fake-proofs

This is the limit I'm trying to solve: $\lim \limits_{x\to1}\left(\frac
x {x-1} - \frac1 {\log(x)}
\right)$

I thought: let's define $x=k+1$, so that $k\to0$ as $x\to1$.

Then it becomes:
$$\lim \limits_{k\to0}\left(\frac
{k+1} {k} - \frac1 {\log(k+1)}
\right)$$
and then,
$$\lim \limits_{k\to0}\left(\frac
{k+1} {k} - \frac1 {\frac {\log(k+1)\times k}k}
\right)=\lim \limits_{k\to0}\left(\frac
{k+1} {k} - \frac1 {k}
\right).$$
Which results in $\frac k k$ , that should be 1, but wolfram says it's $\frac 1 2$...

Did I do something illegal?

Comment: I can't figure out where you from the 3rd limit to the 4th to get the log to disappear

Comment: When you make the logarithm disappear, you're illegally and implicitly using that the product and sum of the limits are the limits of the product and sum.

Comment: I thought that log(k+1)/k -> 1 as k -> 0

Comment: @RiccardoVailati That is still true.

Comment: @GitGud Yes, that's the same limit, but I was asking for a different thing (what's wrong with my solution, rather than how to solve it). If that's still a duplicate, sorry.

Comment: @RiccardoVailati At first I thought you wanted to know what your mistake was, but since you ignored my comment and in the answers you never commented something like "this doesn't answer my question", I thought you were asking how to find the limit, not where your mistake was. I will retract my close vote.

Comment: [This limit found elementary](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554629/find-the-limit-lim-limits-x-to-1-left-fracxx-1-frac1-l).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, the illegal part is this step:
$$\lim_{k \to 0}\frac1{\frac{\log(k + 1)}k}\frac1k = \lim_{k \to 0}\frac1k$$

I see that you applied the known limit
$$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + t)}t = 1$$
but the fact is that
$$\lim_{x \to \alpha}f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x \to \alpha}f(x)\times\lim_{x \to \alpha}g(x)$$
is **only** valid when both limit are finite. In your case you're left with $\lim\limits_{k \to 0}\frac1k$, which not only is not finite, but does not exist entirely.

---

If you are looking for a way to evaluate your limit, I'd suggest MacLauring (that is, a Taylor expansion around $x =0$), which is the simplest and most elegant way. But since you said that you can't use Taylor yet, I fear your only possibility is going with L'Hospital.

Comment: That was the answer I  was looking for, thank you :) I guess half ot the exercise I made were wrong, or I gt the right solution by pure luck :/

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

When $k$ is small, you have by Taylor expansion $$\log(1+k)= k-\frac{k^2}{2}+O\left(k^3\right)$$ and long division gives $$\frac{1}{\log(1+k)}=\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{2}+O\left(k^1\right)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Que tal, amigo ? The old man can be faster (not very often) ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Excelente! Foi a primeira coisa que me veio a cabeça. Of course you can!! Cheers!

Comment: I can't use Taylor yet...

Comment: @RiccardoVailati It's an elegant way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the two fractions, you have $$\lim _{x\to 1} \frac {x\log (x)-x+1}{(x-1)\log (x)}$$

This goes to $\frac 0 0$, so you can use L'hospitals.  Taking the derivative of the top and bottom, you get
$$\lim _{x\to 1}\frac {\log (x)+1-1}{\log (x)+(x-1)x^{-1}}$$ 
Simplifying and multipling top and bottom by x, we get
$$\lim _{x\to 1}\frac {x\log (x)}{x\log (x)+x-1}$$
Again we have $\frac 0 0$, so more L'hospitals and we get
$$\lim _{x\to 1}\frac {\log (x)+1}{\log (x)+1+1}$$
Now we can evaluate, to $\frac 1 2$

Comment: Alright, so that's the correct way to solve this. Now I just have t figure out what was wrong with my solution :)

Comment: This was my first way of doing it too.. +1.